# Highcharts/Highstock: How to move the tooltip position to the center of a dataGroup

Tags: highcharts

Please have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/9u5wdmhp/

The chart has a series with arearange type and forced dataGrouping, looking like this:
[image: The chart has a series of arearange type, the tooltip is pointing at the minimum y-value of the groupData and it displays the range of y-values in the range.]

Obviously the tooltip is pointing at the minimum y-value in the group. However, I need the tooltip to refer to the value in the **center of the dataGroup** (I don't mean the average). Likewise for the sliding "header" at the bottom of the vertical crosshair (it is impossible to see the difference in the example, but I use much more fine-grained data in reality).

A hand-made sketch of what is wanted:
 [image: The tooltip is pointing at the center of the y-values in the dataGroup. The "header " on the x-axis displays the x-value at the center of the dataGroup]

To experiment, my jsfiddle includes a wrapper of the Highcharts Tooltip.positioner function. (Alternatively I could have introduced a section tooltip.positioner in the highcharts chart options, but I prefer to have a wrapper around the original Tooltip.positioner function in order to keep all the functionality it provides, and only modify the y-positioning as described).
Well, I had expected the wrapper to execute when the cursor hovers over the chart, but it does not. I also tried with '[TooltipPositionerCallbackFunction](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.TooltipPositionerCallbackFunction)' instead of 'positioner' without luck.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'positioner', function (proceed, args) {

    console.log("positioner wrapper executing"); // **** this does not run !!?? ***
    
    // how can I get to the point? Is it args.point?
    const start = args.point.dataGroup.start;
    const length = args.point.dataGroup.length;
    
    // index of the central point within the group:
    const cidx = Math.floor((start + length / 2.0)); 

    // get the that point from the series
    const cx = args.point.series.xData[cidx];
    const cy = args.point.series.yData[cidx];
   
    // Here I want to call the original positioner function
    // with the point coordinates { x: cx, y: cy }
    // but I don't know how. 
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
});

$(function () {

    // generate some data
    const x0 = 2592000000;
    const dx = 86400000;
    const n = 900;
    let data = [
        [x0, 10, 20]
    ]; // initial value

    for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) { // construct n values of [timestamp, random, random]
        data[i] = [data[i - 1][0] + dx, 10 + Math.random() * 10, 20 + Math.random() * 10];
    }

    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'data',
            data: data,
            type: 'arearange',
            dataGrouping: {
                forced: true,
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

**EDITS**: I have modified the text and jsfiddle code several times to clarify my intentions and avoid problems with the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the tooltip to refer to the value in the center of the dataGroup (I don't mean the average)

Notice that there is no point, tooltips states to the point - low in this case, between them, is just a path.

> Well, I had expected the wrapper to execute when the cursor hovers over the chart, but it does not.

Look into this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aer86jgb/, check the dev console and explore the tooltip prototype. You should notice that the `positioner` doesn't exist there, that's why your wrapper doesn't work.

Instead of that, I encourage to use the `pointFormatter` callback to calculate the displayed value (the average between the high and low points) and the `positioner` callback to set the tooltip position between the points.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/opzgsL4t/

```
tooltip: {
  pointFormatter() {
    let point = this,
      output = `<span style="color:${point.color}">●</span> ${point.series.name}: <b>${(point.high + point.low) / 2}</b><br/>`;

    return output
  },
        shape: 'rect',
  positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
    let chart = this.chart,
      yAxis = chart.yAxis[0];

    if (point.isHeader) {
      return {
        x: point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - labelWidth / 2,
        y: point.plotY
      }
    } else {
      let lowPxPos = point.plotY,
        highPxPos = yAxis.toPixels(point.high) - chart.plotTop;

      return {
        x: point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10,
        y: (highPxPos + lowPxPos) / 2 - labelHeight / 2,
        isHeader: true
      };
    }
  },
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner

---

EDIT

According to the comments - there is a final solution: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b7ogdayt/

Comment: Thanks, but the middle between point.high and point.low is not useful for my purpose. I need the information available in the ungrouped series data. I need access to the coordinates of the particular point (in the ungrouped data series) which is located in the central X of the grouped data.  I guess that requires access to the series. Is that not possible? Also, as I said, I would prefer to use the wrapper in order to keep the rest of the original tooltip positioning behaviour and not having to re-implement that...

Comment: Let's consider this basic demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cht16p9m/. Here you can find access to the series. Could you point me out what do you have in mind by saying: `I need the information available in the ungrouped series data. I need access to the coordinates of the particular point (in the ungrouped data series) which is located in the central X of the grouped data` Would you like to have an access to the data nested in some grouped range?

Comment: The tooltip should take the (x,y) parameters at the center index of the dataGroup it is hovering over. I mean at the index round(point.dataGroup.start + point.dataGroup.length/2). In my new demo jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/b27cdzrw, in the console, you see the values of the dataGroup dynamically printed out.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that the chart will be used in a webapp to show densely sampled signals. It uses the series.arearange.data type to be able to indicate the dynamic range (min/max) no matter the zooming level. The series data array is like this: [ [x1, y1,y1], [x2,y2,y2], [x3,y3,y3], ...] ; note the two y-values (supposed to be ymin and ymax) are always the same in each datapoint. That way the required appearance is achieved.

Comment: @JakobVinther Thank you for the detailed information! Now I clearly understand your needs. So, when we get the value that we want to display in the tooltip, the last thing to do is setting the position of the tooltip. Here we can use the functionality which I tried to implement before: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lqzd6c3u/, what do you think?

Comment: To be honest, here, I am not sure if you want to show this tooltip always in the middle between those rendered low and high points or show the position of the center nested/hidden point. Here is the way how to show the nested point position: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3fnhrqt8/

Comment: @ Sebastian WędzelI : I mean exactly like in your latest demo, great! Now I just miss the normal tooltip behaviour and label layout (the little arrow pointing at the value and the labels shifting sides close to the chart border). Is it possible to use a wrapper somehow to get those features from the normal tooltip implementation or must I implement/duplicate the code?

Comment: @JakobVinther Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kab6xnt8/ includes the way how to customize the tooltip displayed format of the data and the label. Also, it includes the wrapper with the feature where you can try to customize the position, but it will require more work, and still, I think that using the positioner callback is much easier. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/Core/Tooltip.js#L945. You can try to cusotmize the `renderSplit` function, in case of any trouble I can back to this issue on Monday.

Comment: Also, the way how to set the dateFormat: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.dateTimeLabelFormats

Comment: @ Sebastian Wędzel . Thanks, it is really a great help! To complicate things, my real application has multiple yAxis. I have introduced a second yAxis in the demo jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/9b7v4ukp . Now the tooltipPos variable needs to be an array of positions, one for each series. But I cannot find a way to access the series index from inside the tooltip positioner function. Is that possible? Thanks again! –

Comment: I realize the missing access to the series index from inside the tooltip.positioner function will already be a problem without having multiple yAxis ... having more than one series would already expose the same problem.

Comment: @JakobVinther Let's skip your above question for a while, I have another idea which I want to discuss. My idea is to add a new dummy series (those calculated centered points) that will be hidden, but the tooltip will be enabled. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/an5j4yuo/ What do you think? It's much easier to implement and doesn't have an impact for the performance.

Comment: @ Sebastian Wędzel . That is a very good idea! Much simpler. Based on that I have prepared a new demo http://jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/nbmo590r/ with multiple series and a second yAxis. At this stage it only works partially with some problems that I have not managed to understand. The tooltips don't appear and an "error #18" appears in the console

Comment: @JakobVinther It happens because the defined yAxis in the added series should be also a number, not the whole yAxis object. Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b7ogdayt/

Comment: Thank you very much! With this I have all I need.

Comment: Should we remove some of the many intermediate comments from our discussion?

Comment: @JakobVinther I edited my answer, I think that we can leave the comments, maybe this discussion will be useful for someone else in the future. You can accept my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: One more thing: The transparent series are created in the chart.events.load() function, but  when the chart is zoomed (in x-direction at least), the series must be recalculated and updated, because the grouping will change. What event handler would you recommend to use for that?

Comment: I thought about xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes(), but it is not enough because it does not execute when the chart is being/has been resized, the update is also needed there

Comment: @JakobVinther good point, I think that we can use the `render` callback instead of the `load`, initialize this series earlier with empty data and update the data after each redraw. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e076whtL/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: I need to combine the solutions. Invisible multiple series AND support for zooming and resizing, using the render callback as you suggested. Demo: jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/6juhq9sn . I introduced an id in the series options in order to identify the corresponding transparent series to update. I have trouble with the global variable redrawFlag. I guess one such flag is needed for each series, so I turned the redrawFlag into redrawFlags; an object of flags, each specific to a series by id. However the demo currently does not show any chart. I will be very grateful if you could have a look.

Comment: @JakobVinther Sorry for the late reply. After digging into it deeper I found that using render for multiple series has a terrible effect on the performance and is hard to implement and it is much better to update the series inside the `afterSetExtremes` callback. Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/warn9c78/ Also I used the `linkedTo` feature, it is really useful in this case: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel Thanks! I like it. However, I have found a couple of issues with it.  (1): I noticed the `dataGroup.length` is (correctly) 1 if the zoom is deep enough, but surprisingly it is always 7 with data grouping. Why not more adaptive? 7 may not be enough. In this demo https://jsfiddle.net/jakobvinther/48c3gujr/  the `dataGroup.length` is shown in the tooltip. (2): The dummy series are not updated at *chart resize*, since the `afterSetExtremes` callback is not executed. Perhaps the simplest would be to trigger a full redraw after the resize. Is there is an event callback for that?

Comment: Experimenting with the size of the series, I see that at some stage `dataGroup.length` changes from 7 to to 30

Comment: @user1069609 yes, it is determined by the `dataGrouping`. It calculates and finds the best fit depends on the data range. More options and how to manage the dataGrouping you can find in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel - I am having some problems to get this to work in my application, which is Angular. I am currently preparing a minimal demo. Do you think we should continue with it in this question (which I have accepted as answer already) or should I open a new one?

Comment: @JakobVinther please open a new issue which will include the demo with the sample data and description.

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel Thanks. I have opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64614656/highcharts-angular-update-chart-with-new-options-including-linked-series)