# Highcharts Angular update chart with new options - including linked series

Tags: angular, highcharts

Please see [my edited demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-rew4hj?file=src/app/app.component.ts) that uses the official [highcharts-angular](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular) wrapper.

Initially the chart has a blue series with `type:arearange` and `dataGrouping`, as well as a red overplotted series. Note the tooltips refer to the points of the red series. More info in the demo.

The first button will add another such pair of series. The code uses `addSeries` to do so. ***It works***.

The second button should do the same, *but by changing the chart options* instead of addSeries. It does not work. The new series appears, but all the red series and tooltips disappear. ***The desire is to make this method work!***

I have studied the (nice) [highcharts-angular demos and instructions](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details), but I cannot make it work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to update the `chartOptions`, please don't use any API methods like `update`, `addSeries` or `redraw`.
Instead, focus on the options which are declared in the state- `chartOptions`.
This basically means that you have to convert the `addAllDummySeries` method in order to use that approach.

Please look a the simple example below. We are not using any reverence to the chart, only we are changing the options declared above, not that one generated by Highcharts. By changing the state we are telling Angular to make a redraw.
**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-hktwwr

Also in my opinion using the `oneToOne` flag set to true is not a good idea.
Please see the difference in the demo below. 
**Demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-w5pnwd

Comment: Thanks. I followed your advice and has come to [this version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-crwulk?file=src/app/app.component.ts). However, the series do not have the nested `linkedSeries` objects ... what am I missing?

Comment: I think there is something still missing in the `addAllDummySeries` method. Please tell me what this function should do?

Comment: The `addAllDummySeries` method should loop over all series in the chart. If a series has a `linkedSeries` member, the series' data will be assigned to values which are taken from the corresponding `linkedSeries`, namely the values in the centers of its dataGroups. Maybe I should refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64358169/highcharts-highstock-how-to-move-the-tooltip-position-to-the-center-of-a-datagr?noredirect=1&lq=1) I had with @Sebastian Wędzel, in particular his comment at Oct 20 at 18:35 .

Comment: In the `addAllDummySeries` using `chartOptions` you won't have properties like `points`, `xData`, `yData` etc. because this object is not generated by Highcharts and  it won't have these properties. It only has properties which you declared above. So you have to change the way you declare that dummy data, for example to something similar to what I did in the demo below.
Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-bsppcj